# Android studio; Extract text from spinner which includes both text and an image

Tags: android

So for a currency converter, I have two spinners, and each has some text and an image: a text with the currency name, and then an image which is the flag of the corresponding country. 
now with the addition of the flag, I no longer know how to extract the text (currency name) of the spinner. this currency name is necessary for the conversion.

does anyone know how I can do it?

Thank you!

Comment: You can overwrite your spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener to do your bidding

Comment: can you please be more specific?